# How to find out when started and finished JSONDeserializer?

Tags: java, jackson

I need to calculate some data in my object which I get from JSON. That is my JSON object:

```
{
   "myObject": {
       "controlPoints": [10,15,20,25]
   }
}
```

and that is my class which mapped to this JSON:

```
public class MyObject {
   public List<Float> controlPoints;
   public Float width;

   public MyObject() {
       width = controlPoints.get(0) / controlPoints.get(2); // in this point my controlPoints is empty.
   }
}
```

how can I calculate width using `controlPoints` which was getting from JSON in a construct phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@JsonCreator` to make your constructor as `Deserializer` for Jackson:

```
@JsonCreator
public MyObject(List<Float> controlPoints, Float width) {
      this.controlPoints = controlPoints;
      this.width = this.controlPoints.get(0) / this.controlPoints.get(2);
}
```

**OR**

You can create a method as `PostConstruct` to call it right after the constructor

```
@PostConstruct
public void calculateWidth(){
    this.width = this.controlPoints.get(0) / this.controlPoints.get(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in the default constructor as all values (such as `controlPoints`) are set after the constructor is called. The JSON mapper first creates that instance, then afterwards sets the data, usually using setters.

Best practice would to be create a getter for `width` such as

```
public Float getWidth() {
  width = controlPoints.get(0) / controlPoints.get(2);
}
```

and call it afterwards.

You could also calculcate the width inside `setControlPoints` since that's the first point in time when the data is available.